# Python folium - Leaflet plugin not visible on the map

Tags: python, leaflet, javascript, folium

I would like to inject Leaflet plugin into Python folium map.

After applying the following code:

```
map.get_root().header.add_child(folium.CssLink("https://pasichnykvasyl.github.io/Leaflet.BigImage/src/Leaflet.BigImage.css"))
map.get_root().html.add_child(folium.JavascriptLink("https://pasichnykvasyl.github.io/Leaflet.BigImage/src/Leaflet.BigImage.js"))

png_js = '''
L.control.bigImage({position: 'topleft'}).addTo{map};
'''.replace("{map}", mapJsVar)

map.get_root().script.add_child(Element(png_js))
```

I can't see the plugin anywhere on my map.
Despite the demo version, which programmatically looks exactly the same
https://pasichnykvasyl.github.io/Leaflet.BigImage/

My console says nothing.

Where did I make mistake then?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `png_js` , change `.addTo{map}` to `.addTo({map})` and wrap JS code in `$(document).ready(function(){ ... });`

Code:

```
import folium

m = folium.Map()

m.get_root().header.add_child(folium.CssLink('https://pasichnykvasyl.github.io/Leaflet.BigImage/src/Leaflet.BigImage.css'))
m.get_root().html.add_child(folium.JavascriptLink('https://pasichnykvasyl.github.io/Leaflet.BigImage/src/Leaflet.BigImage.js'))

png_js = '''
$(document).ready(function(){
  L.control.bigImage({position: 'topleft'}).addTo({map});
});
'''.replace("{map}", m.get_name())

m.get_root().script.add_child(folium.Element(png_js))

m
```

[image]

When using the plugin, you probably get CORS policy error displayed on console, which is an off-topic issue unrelated to the question:

> Access to image at 'https://a.tile.openstreetmap.org/1/-1/1.png' from
> origin 'http://localhost:8888' has been blocked by CORS policy: No
> 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource.

Comment: That's perfect! Now I realized, that bounding every standalone Leaflet code in the JQuery function is a mandatory thing to make it working. Is that correct?

Comment: Not mandatory actually. It is required because folium injects the JS code to a place before the line where map object is created.